# Center ImageView Vertically with offset

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

I would like to center an image view horizontally and then also center the view vertically. However, on the vertical centering I need the image view to be slightly off-center favoring the top half of the view. My designer gave me a top spacing of 214 points which on the iPhone 6,7,8 works perfect. However on the iPad it doesn't scale correctly. On the other end of the spectrum with an iPhone 4S the image view is favoring the bottom half of the view.

**iPhone 8** (The image below is a screenshot of interface builder set for iPhone 8.)
[image]

**iPad** (The image below is a screenshot of interface builder set for iPad Pro 9.7". )
[image]

**iPhone 4S** (The image below is a screenshot of interface builder set for iPhone 4S.)
[image]

How can I get this to scale for all screen sizes?

Comment: [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might solve it by applying constraints from the storyboard (`centerXAnchor, centerYAnchor-offset`):

[image]

[image]

and eventually with size class variation:

[image]

I show you how to solve it by code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let IMAGE_SIZE:CGFloat = 200 // whatever
    let OFFSET:CGFloat = -60 // whatever

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let niceIcon = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icon"))
        self.view.addSubview(niceIcon)

        niceIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        niceIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: IMAGE_SIZE).isActive = true
        niceIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: IMAGE_SIZE).isActive = true
        niceIcon.centerXAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        niceIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: OFFSET).isActive = true
    }
}
```

---

the point is: don't use top/left/right/bottom anchor, just use centerX and centerY (with negative offset)